# Optimize Multiple Select Queries on Large Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, indexing

I'm trying increase the performance of a bunch of SELECT count(DISTINCT id) queries that I'm running in a webpage by creating an indexed view. Currently it takes about 9 seconds for these queries to run (there are about 14 of them and they're all very similar). The table I am querying has 7.1 million records.

Basically I have a table with columns that contain long strings (UserAgents) with keywords like "iPhone" or "Android" that I'm trying to select against. Previously I was extracting "iPhone" from the useragent by using WHERE useragent LIKE '%iPhone%'. Knowing that LIKE wildcard is computationally expensive, I made a view that does this and assigns e.g. "iPhone" to an integer value, so now I can select against my view e.g WHERE useragent = 2. Which should be faster right? I even indexed the view, and I am getting no improvement in performance on these queries.

Here's an example of one of the queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT message_id) AS Amount
FROM emailClientUsageView
WHERE HTMLID = 4736 AND (EC = 8 AND UA != 2 AND UA != 3);
```

How can I optimize the table, view, database, and/or queries to get these queries to run in a reasonable amount of time ( < 2 seconds )?

EDIT:
Table:
Columns: id, htmlid, msgid, dt, UserAgent, Referrer, EmailClient

Added index on table: unique clustered index on UserAgent, id
nonunique nonclustered index on EmailClient

View:

```
SELECT id, msgid, HTMLID,
    CASE
        WHEN Referrer LIKE '%aol%' THEN 1
        WHEN Referrer = '' THEN 99
        ELSE 0
        END AS ref, 
    CASE
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 1
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%iPad%' THEN 2
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%iPod%' THEN 3
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%Microsoft Office%' THEN 4
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%Mozilla%' THEN 5
        WHEN UserAgent LIKE '%Android%' THEN 6
        ELSE 0
        END AS UA, 
    CASE
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 1
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE 'internet explorer%' THEN 2
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Outlook%' THEN 3
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%yahoo%' THEN 4
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%safari%' THEN 5
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Android%' THEN 6
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%gmail%' THEN 7
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Windows%' THEN 8
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%AOL%' THEN 9
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Thunderbird%' THEN 10
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Lotus Notes%' THEN 11
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Palm%' THEN 12
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '%Entourage%' THEN 13
        WHEN EmailClient LIKE '' THEN 99
        ELSE 0
        END AS EC
FROM store_openEmail AS emailClientUsageView
```

Indices on view: unique clustered on id, nonunique nonclustered on EmailClient

Comment: Why do you think indexing a view creates magical performance benefits? If the view has the same number of rows as the base table, you don't really gain anything by having it.

Comment: I thought that indexing would allow the index to be grouped/clustered/more organized such that query WHERE would be faster

Comment: Indexed views are usually used when you want to pre-aggregate calculations such as `COUNT`. They are unlikely to help if all they're doing is creating an extra copy of the same set of rows. You're much better off normalizing the user agent data (in a lookup table, not an indexed view) and making sure you have proper indexes (maybe even filtered indexes) that support the where clauses.

Comment: Add the **exact** schema, including any indexes you added.

Comment: @Brandon Brown : Did you mean `EC != 8`? Otherwise the other two conditions does not add anything.

Comment: Not for that sort of query. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921(v=sql.100).aspx. PS if PC = 8, how can it EC != 1 ever be false ?

Comment: Yes, I removed the extra EC != parts as they were unnecessary. Nevertheless, no noticeable improvement in performance

Comment: Any time you have a wildcard at the beginning of a varchar field, the optimizer cannot use the index.  Avoid that.  You could use computed & persisted fields at the end, but that's a funky way of doing it.  You really need to shred the data as it's going into the database and normalize it somehow (like @AaronBertrand said).

Comment: That view doesn't help.  You'd probably be better off parsing the user agents and email clients into short, indexable fields before inserting them into the database.

Comment: I previously tried adding a computed column that converts the UserAgent into an integer but that didnt help either. Nothing I try seems to work..

Comment: GOT IT! I added an index for HTMLID and THAT resulted in a dramatic improvement. I added an index on almost all the other fields to no avail. Not sure why HTMLid field specifically resulted in such a drastic improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this index on the view: HtmlId, EC, UA, MsgId.
That will cover the query you listed, and also force the EC and UA columns to be pre-computed.
I'm assuming that MsgId and Message_Id are intended to be the same.

It may not help with other queries, though.  Adding Ref and Id to the end may help with others, but that depends on those queries.

See also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd171921%28SQL.100%29.aspx